# How to fix error "closing unused connection"

Tags: r, exception, csv, connection

To read in the first 5 columns of `Test.csv` I may go:

```
x <- matrix(scan(pipe(paste0("cut -f1,2,3,4,5 -d, ","/home/test/Test.csv")),skip=1,sep=","),ncol=5)
```

Then if I read it using a normal method:

```
y <- read.csv("/home/test/Test.csv")
```

I get the error message:

```
Warning message:
closing unused connection 3 (cut -f1,2,3,4,5 -d, /home/test/Test.csv)
```

Is this error message a problem, and if so how do I remedy it?

Comment: Try assigning the connection returned by `pipe` to an object and `close` it explicitly after using `scan`.

Comment: @Roland Can you give an example

Comment: It's not an error. Only a warning.

Answer (score 8):

I cannot replicate the warning on my system. However, you could try closing the connection explicitly:

```
con <- pipe(paste0("cut -f1,2,3,4,5 -d, ","/home/test/Test.csv"))
x <- matrix(scan(con,skip=1,sep=","),ncol=5)
close(con)
```